# Can't create trigger using SQLPlus in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm Learning Oracle and wanted to try creating a trigger. I tried this example form a book in sqlplus.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER policy_bull BEFORE insert or update
  2  ON emp
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    :new.salary := 200;
  6  END
  7  /
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS

even though I logged in as SYS using

sqlplus "sys/oracle as sysdba"

Comment: can you try it without semicolons?

Comment: Did the book tell you to log in as sys? sys is similar to the "root" user in unix - only used for administering the system. Typically the first thing you'd do with a new Oracle instance is create a user who will own the objects for an application. For experiments you may find the user "scott", password "tiger" has already been created for this purpose (however, on a new instance, you may have to unlock the account first).

Answer (score 7):

You need to type / on a blank line to tell SQLPLUS to run the statement.

Comment: This literally took me a day to figure out. Thank you very much. The missing "/" slash was causing my trigger to be created with some other PL/SQL written after the "END" keyword. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Oracle forbids creating triggers on objects owned by SYS.

Did you create the table emp as SYS? You probably want to be a regular user to do that. emp doesn't sound like a system table.

Comment: good catch. It looks like someone may have run the example tables ("emp" is a table in the standard examples schema) while they were logged in as SYS.

Answer (score 0):

I think a semi-colon is missing after END.
Also mention SYS.emp

Answer (score 0):

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER policy_bull BEFORE insert or update
  2  of SALARY on EMP
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    :new.salary := 200;
  6  END
  7  /

you have to type the column where the "NEW SALARY" is ppl its SALARY so ...or update of SALARY on EMP...